# What does "-p" mean in the link of page.php-p?

Tags: php, http

I work in a php 5.6 based project. I see some links are like that "www.domain.com/page.php-p?mode=abc". What does "-p" mean in the "php-p" part ?

Comment: Maybe the target file actually has that extension? It's an unusual extension but I'm not aware that it has any special meaning, although someone may come along and correct me

Comment: I would start by checking the web server configuration.